# environment variables in shiny-server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, shiny, shiny-server

I'm trying to deploy a shiny app using `shiny-server`. That app uses the [`aws.s3`](https://github.com/cloudyr/aws.s3) package to read some files from an S3 bucket, which requires the AWS credentials either be stored in environment variables or in an `.Renviron` file.

Understandably, [shiny-server scrubs most environment variables before launching R](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/shiny-discuss/nNs0kztwdWo/90InjZXfAPEJ). Is there any way to square this circle? Any other mechanism I could use to pass credentials to aws.s3?

Comment: Is the `shiny-server` running in AWS?

Comment: @helloV Yes, it is. Inside a docker container.

Answer (score 0):

when running your docker container, you can in the same command provide your .Renviron and / or aws-credentials file to the correct place with -v flag:

```
docker run -v /location_file_local/.Renviron:/location_file_docker/.Renviron Name_of_docker_image
```